# How do i change my buttons sizes to fit my border?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am following fireship's angular for beginner's video. However, I am running into an issue where the buttons and their text are too small but they do input correctly when i click within the area.
here is a link to the video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0bBLvWXBvc&t=888s&ab_channel=Fireship)
And here is a link to my github repo if you would like to see my code.
[github](https://github.com/NoeMuniz/tictactoe_angular.git)
Hope someone can help

I tried to change the font-size but that didn't seem to work and would only move the button within the bordered area.

[tictactoe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJPVj.png)

Comment: Hi Noe and welcome to stackoverflow. It's quite hard trying to help if you don't really show where it is going wrong and add a link to a repo. Can you maybe add a screenshot of where it went wrong + the code for that section? That'll help the community to try and help you :) Thanks.

Comment: i added links for my github and a link to a picture for the website. hope I did it properly and hope you can help.